# How to setup alternative path for binding (Gnat ADA)

Tags: ubuntu, ada, gnat

I try to compile a sample ada sourcefile, using libncursesada binding. 
Gnat, during compilation, can't find libncursesada, installed with apt-get.

Software configuration : 
GNAT 7.3.0
xubuntu 18.04

code :

-- hello.adb

```
with Terminal_Interface.Curses; use Terminal_Interface.Curses;

procedure Hello is
  C : Key_Stroke;
  Msg : String := "Hello, world!";

begin
  Init_Windows;          
  Add(Standard_Window, Msg, Msg'Length); 
  Refresh;                              
  C := Get_Keystroke;                  
  End_Windows;                        
  Curses_Free_All;
end Hello;
```

Compilation error :

```
gnat compile hello.adb
gcc-7 -c hello.adb
hello.adb:1:06: file "terminal_interface.ads" not found
gnatmake: "hello.adb" compilation error
```

libncursesada packages are installed with apt-get :

```
libncursesada-doc/bionic,bionic,now 6.0.20170708-2 all  [installé]
  Ada binding to the ncurses text interface library: documentation

libncursesada5/bionic,now 6.0.20170708-2 amd64  [installé, automatique]
  Ada binding to the ncurses text interface library: shared library

libncursesada5-dev/bionic,now 6.0.20170708-2 amd64
```

Files can be fount into this directory : 
/usr/share/ada/adainclude/ncursesada/

```
/usr/share/ada/adainclude/ncursesada$ ls -l terminal_interface.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3115 août   9  2017 terminal_interface.ads
```

When I compile using a standard binding (Gnat.IO for example), all is ok, so I suppose I must specify where to find this other binding ads file to compiler.

I can't find instructions about this into this binding documentation (libncursesada-doc folder), how to setup for compiling and linking.

What is the recommended way ?

I have read some instructions for other additionnals bindings, like add path to PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH into .bashrc.
A parameter to add into a gpr file ?

Thanks.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libncursesada-dev` includes a GPRBuild project file:

```
/usr/share/ada/adainclude/ncursesada.gpr
```

So the easiest way to link against it would be to use [GPRBuild](http://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug.html) as build system:

```
with "ncursesada";

project Hello is
   -- should suffice for your example
   for Main use ("hello.adb");
end Hello;
```

You may need to set the `GPR_PROJECT_PATH` environment variable to include `/usr/share/ada/adainclude` so that the `ncursesada.gpr` project can be found; I am unsure whether debian sets that up correctly for you.

Having saved the above as `hello.gpr`, you can compile your code with

```
gprbuild hello.gpr
```

Comment: No need to add the path, it is a standard location for Ada libraries built with the system gnat compiler.

Comment: Thank you for you detailled answer and link to external documentation. 
It works fine now, compil bind and link operations are successfull. For ubuntu users which may face the same problem, ncursesada.gpr is located into /usr/share/gpr folder. 
If tryed GPR_PROJECT_PATH setup at /usr/share/gpr , or GRP_PROJECT_PATH reset at null : both are working fine. So the solution is GPRBuild use.
Best regards.